# Why does calling SUM on a CASE expression give "missing right parenthesis"?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to calculate the total value of orders placed by each shopper. This can be done as

```
SELECT idShopper, bi.price * bi.quantity FROM bb_shopper LEFT OUTER JOIN bb_basket bb USING (idShopper) FULL OUTER JOIN bb_baksetitem bi USING (idbasket) WHERE orderPlaced = 1
```

However, I want to get 0 for shoppers without placed order. This returns what you would expect:

```
SELECT idShopper, bi.price * CASE orderPlaced WHEN 1 THEN bi.quantity ELSE 0 END AS quantity FROM bb_shopper 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bb_basket bb USING (idShopper)
    FULL OUTER JOIN bb_basketitem bi USING (idbasket)
```

But trying to SUM ... GROUP BY gives ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
SELECT SUM(bi.price * CASE orderPlaced WHEN 1 THEN bi.quantity ELSE 0 END AS quantity) FROM bb_shopper 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bb_basket bb USING (idShopper)
    FULL OUTER JOIN bb_basketitem bi USING (idbasket)
    GROUP BY idShopper;
```

I believe I'm using oracle 11g

Comment: Try `SELECT SUM(bi.price * CASE orderPlaced WHEN 1 THEN bi.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS quantity` (moving the right parenthesis left a bit)

Answer (score 1):

The clause `as quantity` names the newly summed field. So it needs to be outside the `SUM` expression, ie outside the parenthesis.

```
SELECT SUM(bi.price * CASE orderPlaced WHEN 1 THEN bi.quantity ELSE 0 END) as quantity 
FROM bb_shopper
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bb_basket bb USING (idShopper)
    FULL OUTER JOIN bb_basketitem bi USING (idbasket)
    GROUP BY idShopper;
```

The [Case expression reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html) has a similar example. I now see @seanb has made a similar comment.

Comment: Note a typo - missing the first line of the FROM

Comment: All good. Given it a thumbs up as I think it's the correct & useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the use of a full outer join.  If you want to keep all shoppers, then `LEFT JOIN` should be sufficient.  I find it hard to imagine that your data model supports basket items without a valid basket id.

I assume that `orderPlaced` is from the baskets table.  You should qualify all column names in your query (except for the ones from the `USING` clause).

Then, if `orderPlaced` only takes on the values `0` and `1`, you can simplify the logic to:

```
SELECT idShopper,
       SUM(bi.price * bb.orderPlaced * bi.quantity) AS quantity
FROM bb_shopper s LEFT JOIN
     bb_basket bb
     USING (idShopper) LEFT JOIN
     bb_basketitem bi
     USING (idbasket)
GROUP BY idShopper;
```

The fundamental issue is the misplaced closing paren, but there seems to be room for improvement in other areas as well.